# Updating XAMPP broke php web page execution

Tags: php, xampp, htdocs

I use a windows 10 64-bit desktop and a windows 10 also 64-bit laptop. This has happened on both computers.

After doing a complete uninstall of an old version of XAMPP(in Admin account), I reinstalled the newest version (xampp-win32-7.3.1-0-VC15-installer.exe as an Admin with Firewall and virus protection disabled).

I verified the install by typing localhost/ into my Chrome brower and it came up with the XAMPP web page at localhost/dashboard.

I then loaded the db backup into phpMyAdmin 4.8.4. And I copied the backup folder of my pages into htdocs.

But now the php web pages that displayed correctly in the old version now throw this error on some pages, not all.

```
Warning: require_once(/includes/session.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_rabbits\my_profile.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/includes/session.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_rabbits\my_profile.php on line 1
```

I checked the paths and they are all correct - no misspellings. My includes folder is in htdocs as is the individual my_profile.php page. Here is what line 1 looks like of my_profile.php page:

```
<?php require_once("/includes/session.php"); ?>
```

Here is what my includes/session.php code looks like:

```
<?php

   session_start();

   function message() {
      if (isset($_SESSION["message"])) {
         $output = "<div class=\"message\">";
         $output .= htmlentities($_SESSION["message"]);
         $output .= "</div>";

         // clear message after use
         $_SESSION["message"] = null;

         return $output;
      }
   }

   function errors() {
      if (isset($_SESSION["errors"])) {
         $errors = $_SESSION["errors"];

         // clear message after use
         $_SESSION["errors"] = null;

         return $errors;
      }
   }

?>
```

Thanks for any help you could give. I am a novice user and navigating in unknown waters...

Comment: If `includes` is inside `htdocs`, then `/includes/session.php` cannot be its absolute path.

Comment: Not sure I understand.. both my_profile.php file and includes folder are in the same directory, "my_rabbits". Do I need to specify the path with the prefix "htdocs/my_rabbits"? 

I also don't understand how it worked perfectly on the old version just the night before. I wonder if the new version has some setting changes that the old one did not have. Or do you have to write the code differently now? its been awhile since I have written php.

Comment: Please have a look at [What is the difference between a relative and absolute path?](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm). I'm not aware of any relevant change in the PHP interpreter regarding path handling so if including stuff in `/includes` used to work even though you didn't have a `C:\includes` directory, I honestly don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include_path in php.ini - no current path

```
include_path = ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR"
```

Comment: Will that make any difference for *absolute* paths?

Comment: In some windows installations  /path1/path2 = relative; C:\path1\path2 = absolute.

Comment: Interesting... I'll try to test that if I can put my hands in some older version.

Comment: You will find this interesting...I did as you said - found the php.ini file and found all the include_path references and found that the Unix line was uncommented and then found the one for Windows and added the code you suggested. The default one was one that was just include_path = ".;c:\php\includes. This triggered a thought to go check the xampp_old folders php.ini and sure enough, it had the same line of code. I must have changed it 5 years ago and didn't remember.  I saved the new code and tried it but it still did not work. ***See part 2 of this comment ***

Comment: Part 2 of Comment:

Comment: Then, I followed the php5.5 forum link that you posted and tried what they suggested by putting a period in front of my require_once statements like <?php require_once("./includes/session.php"); ?> It worked! I now need to go into every broken page and make this little tweak and I'll be good to go. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: If you're fixing code, then it's easier to just switch to absolute paths so your code won't break because of server settings: `__DIR__ . '/includes/...'`.

Comment: Interestingly too, the code I have in other pages that was just "include" verses "require_once" will run fine with just the "includes/session.php" where the "require_once" had to have the "./" prefacing all the files in the path "./includes/session.php".